# Are there any good VoIP service tutorials out there?

Tags: android, voip

Does anyone know any good tutorials for VoIP apps on android? Browser functionality would also be good but not necessary. I'm mostly looking for a softphone and server side tutorial.

Comment: What are you trying to ask? be specific!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sadly not going to found a tutorials on VoIp but a good place to start is at http://developer.android.com/training/building-connectivity.html.